# Dual SAN controller failure

Tags: storage, storage-area-network, data-recovery

I am new to storage but facing a serious disaster issue of the failure of Dual SAN Controller. Don't know whether this is a right place to ask this question. Anyways the problem is, None of the controllers starting up, Primary controller stuck on Brand Name & Model where as secondary controller stuck on asking for WWN. Initially disk failure occurred, we replaced it and rebuilding started but after some time controller stopped responding. Other healthy Volumes were working fine even during the rebuild process. Wanted to know the ways for recovering data from the dead controller?? 
Just for curiosity Can I use working controller of another SAN of same make and model with this disk enclosures, will it work ?? What are the chances of recovering the data. Already lodged a support request to the vendor but it's taking long to resolve

Comment: Do you think we can answer this with the vague information you've given us? How about some information about the storage make and model? How about the server make and model? How about some technical details about your configuration?

Comment: Storage is of HP EVA 6000 Series with Dual Controller configured for Failover, with 3 JBODs, all disk were in RAID 5 and all servers were connected through Cisco MDS 9000 Fibre Switch only. HP EVA Storage works command view is installed on HP Proliant DL380 G6 whose OS is Windows Storage Server

Comment: *What are the chances of recovering the data.* Restore from backups to other storage.

Answer (score 3):

In your situation, I would focus on harassing the hardware vendor support to do the troubleshoot and propose an action plan instead of playing lego with other arrays in your datacenter. For storage vendors, data unavailability issue is the highest priority support tickets, so HP should answer you very soon.

Comment: In addition to what was said above: Do not reconnect drive-enclosures to another HP EVA system yourself, you can destroy the rest of the data.